# Data Structure for Library Management Project

Tags: c, data-structures

Which Data Structure should be used for a Library Management Project?

There are 5 operations:

- Buy a book
- Buy a new copy of a book
- Rent a book
- Return back a book
- delete a copy of a book

I know Hash Tables and AVL-Trees at the moment.

I started my project with AVL, but I am not sure if it's the right choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve(performance, extensibility, simplicity), the above operations can be implemented with simple data structure like array or linked list.

I recommand using simple data structure to implement your application first. When performance become a problem, consider other data structures like Hashtable, AVL tree, etc.

Comment: I can't use Array structure. Only dynamic structure like Linked List. Performance is the main goal and two operations need to be with recursion.